# GoogleDrive let user authenticate

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api

I'm trying to implement GoogleDrive into my .net application
but on the tutorial i'm using from http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/ it says that it simply send the user to a login page of GoogleDrive but the question is where ? i don't see any code that sends the user to a login page.

so my question is how can i let the user authenticate before starting of?

Trying several days now and i don't have a clue how to do it.
hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [External Authentication Services with ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services). MVC supports many external providers and is reasonably easy to implemented them within Visual Studio and a MVC project.

For implementing a login from ASP.NET have a look at the [OAuth 2.0 Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc). You can also have a look at this MVC tutorial [MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on C#](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) - it contains exactly what you ask for - a redirect to the Google login page.

---

The Access-URL's are embedded into the Nuget-Package **Google.Drive.API.v2/Auth/Client** - when you use the assembly/the classes the url's are internally known:

[image]

A thorough explanation (and also the URL's when using pure REST to access the service) could be found here [GDrive .NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/dotnet) and here [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Comment: Your example is in Java. And does it show where to redirect ?

Comment: The page I posted is the **.NET Quickstart**. Nuget packages exists only for .NET Projects (see screenshot). The google documentation has examples in many different programming languages Java/C#/PHP/etc. - you need to select the desired language. The REST documentation is programming language agnostic. Please take your time to study the documentation more thoroughly.

Comment: Hmm ye i need to study abit more but its strange if i try to use some calls im not getting redirected to the login page from GoogleDrive  thats weird

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to the ASP.NET Web login example for Google sites. I did initially misunderstood your question - I thought you are asking about where the URL's are stored.

Comment: No problem :) also nice to know it are constants can ya also use the mvc once for web application without mvc razor